# Should I transpose features or weights in Neural network?

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, pytorch

I am learning Neural network.

Here is the complete piece of code:
https://github.com/udacity/deep-learning-v2-pytorch/blob/master/intro-to-pytorch/Part%201%20-%20Tensors%20in%20PyTorch%20(Exercises).ipynb

When I transpose features, I get the following output:

```
import torch
def activation(x):
    return 1/(1+torch.exp(-x))

### Generate some data
torch.manual_seed(7) # Set the random seed so things are predictable

# Features are 5 random normal variables
features = torch.randn((1, 5))
# True weights for our data, random normal variables again
weights = torch.randn_like(features)
# and a true bias term
bias = torch.randn((1, 1))

product = features.t() * weights + bias
output = activation(product.sum())
```

> tensor(0.9897)

However, if I transpose weights, I get a different output:

```
weights_prime = weights.view(5,1)
prod = torch.mm(features, weights_prime) + bias
y_hat = activation(prod.sum())
```

> tensor(0.1595)

Why does this happen?

---

### Update

I took a look at the solution:
https://github.com/udacity/deep-learning-v2-pytorch/blob/master/intro-to-pytorch/Part%201%20-%20Tensors%20in%20PyTorch%20(Solution).ipynb

And I saw this:

`y = activation((features * weights).sum() + bias)`

why can a matrix features(1,5) multiply another matrix weights(1,5) without transposing weights first?

### Update 2

After read several posts, I realized that

matrixA * matrixB is different from torch.mm(matrixA,matrixB) and torch.matmul(matrixA,matrixB).

Could someone confirm my three understandings between?

1. So the * means element-wise multiplication, whereas torch.mm() and torch.matmul() are matrix-wise multiplication.
2. differences between torch.mm() and torch.matmul(): mm() is used specifically for 2 dimensions matrix, whereas matmul() can be used for more complicated cases.
3. In Neutral Network for this Udacity coding exercise mentioned in my above link, it needs element-wise multiplication.

### Update 3

Just to bring in the Video screenshot for someone who has the same confusion:

[image]

And here is the video link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=98&v=6Z7WntXays8&feature=emb_logo

Comment: For your update 2: Yes, `*` is used for element-wise multiplication. This does broadcasting, which is why the row vector `*` a column vector results in an outer product. `torch.matmul` supports scenarios than `torch.mm`, and also does broadcasting. For the Udacity example, element-wise multiplication works since it's followed by a sum, which results in a dot product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at https://pytorch.org/docs/master/generated/torch.nn.Linear.html

The typical linear (fully connected) layer in torch uses input features of shape  `(N,∗,in_features)` and weights of shape `(out_features,in_features)` to produce an output of shape `(N,*,out_features)`. Here N is the batch size, and * is any number of other dimensions (may be none).

The implementation is:

```
output = input.matmul(weight.t())
```

So, the answer is that neither of your formulas is correct according to convention; the standard formula is the one above.

You may use a non-standard shape since you're implementing things from scratch; as long as it's consistent it may work, but I don't recommend it for learning.  It's unclear what 1 and 5 is in your code, but presumably you want 5 input features and one output feature, with a batch size of 1 as well.  In which case the standard shapes should be input = `torch.randn((1, 5))` for batch size=1 and in_features=5, and weights = `torch.randn((5, 1))` for in_features=5 and out_features=1.

There is no reason why weights should ever be the same shape as features; thus `weights = torch.randn_like(features)` doesn't make sense.

Lastly, for your actual questions:

"Should I transpose features or weights in Neural network?" - in torch convention, you should transpose weights, but use matmul with the features first.  Other frameworks may have a different convention; as long as in_features dimension of the weights is multiplied by the num_features dimension of the input, it would work.

"Why does this happen?" - these are two completely different calculations; there is no reason to think they would produce the same result.

"So the * means element-wise multiplication, whereas torch.mm() and torch.matmul() are matrix-wise multiplication." - Yes; mm is matrix-matrix only, matmul is vector-matrix or matrix-matrix, including batched versions of same - check the docs for everything matmul can do (which is kinda a lot).

"differences between torch.mm() and torch.matmul(): mm() is used specifically for 2 dimensions matrix, whereas matmul() can be used for more complicated cases." - Yes; the big difference is that matmul can broadcast.  Use it when you specifically intend that; use mm to prevent unintentional broadcasting.

"In Neutral Network for this Udacity coding exercise mentioned in my above link, it needs element-wise multiplication." - I doubt it; it's probably an error in the Udacity code.  This bit of code `weights = torch.randn_like(features)` looks like an error in any case; the dimensions of weights have a meaning different from the dimensions of features.

Comment: thanks a lot for the detailed explanation. The explanation for how a typical linear layer should be does give me a better understanding of it. But I get confused when you say: weights of shape ```(out_features, in_features)```. For example, if I have an NN for recognizing bird, the output is True or False, the the out_features is 1, also assume in_features=10000 . So according to your explanation the shape of weights is (1, 10000) which means the weights only have 1 row. But I saw the weights have multiple rows when I was training the bird model. How could you explain this?

Comment: hi @Alex, I updated my question also, included the link to the complete code example. This exercise comes from Udacity. Like you said: ```weights = torch.randn_like(features)``` doesn't make sense. I found it's hard to understand.

Comment: @Franva " the output is True or False, the the out_features is 1, also assume in_features=10000 . So according to your explanation the shape of weights is (1, 10000) which means the weights only have 1 row." - Yes, that is correct: one output means the weights (in the last layer) would have shape (1, something)

Comment: thanks man, could you please see my update 2 about the 3 things to confirm?  after these 3 confirmations received, I should be able to clear all my confusion.

Comment: @Franva Sure, answered.  For this level of detail, a bounty would be appropriate.

Comment: Hi Alex, I have updated my question with the screenshot from the tutorial. It does requires dot product.

Answer (score 1):

This line is taking an outer product between the two vectors.

```py
product = features.t() * weights + bias
```

The resulting shape is `5x5`.

If you change this to a dot product, then `output` will match `y_hat`.

```py
product = torch.mm(weights, features.t()) + bias
```

Comment: thanks @danny for the answer. So NN requires a dot product not an outer product, correct? And also, if I do the dot product between the 2, feathers and weights, then in this case the order of the features and weights will not matter, am I correct?

Comment: The order of features and weights wouldn't matter for a dot product, but they will matter when using `torch.mm` to compute the dot product, since that function performs matrix multiplication. To use matrix multiplication for a dot product, the first argument should be a row vector and the second argument a column vector.

Comment: Regarding whether NNs require dot products, that's a general way to think about how each unit's activation is computed, prior to applying a bias and activation function. The dot products are often combined such that an entire layer's dot product calculations can be calculated with a single matrix multiplication of a weight matrix and the activity vector from the preceding layer.

Comment: thanks Danny, you suggested me to use ```torch.mm()```, while others suggested ```torch.matmul()```. What are the differences? and Which one should I use?

Comment: `torch.mm` and `torch.matmul` both perform matrix multiplication, but the former does not [broadcast](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/notes/broadcasting.html) (automatically expand Tensors where applicable) and the latter does.

Comment: thanks man, could you please see my update 2 about the 3 things to confirm?